# How to apply a polynomial to a sequence

Tags: matlab, matrix, polynomials

I am implementing Wiedemann method and it has a key point that I did not understand. I post here and hope you can help me.This is my question:
[image]

**This is my solution**; however I **am not sure** about my solution in matlab

```
g=[1,2,0,0,2] %coefficient of g(z)
%% compute coefficient of g(z^-1)
g_minus=[]%I don't know how to compute
s=[1,1,0]
g_z=conv(g_minus,s) %applying a polynomial  to the sequence
```

UPDATE:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't understand your notation, but you can multiply polynomials using the `conv` function on their coefficient vectors.

Comment: Do you think the coefficient of g(z) and g(z^-1) are similar? In the formula they use g(z^-1). You can see page 2 at this paper to get more detail http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~moreno/CS424/Ressources/WIEDEMANN-IEEE-1986.pdf

Comment: `g(z^-1)` has descending powers instead of ascending powers, so probably it is just reversed, like `g_minus = g(end:-1:1)`

Comment: What's a *polynominal*? Don't you rather mean *polynomial*?

Comment: @Jubobs: Sorry. It is wrong word. It must be polynomial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation [i] means taking the coefficient of z^i. Notice that i runs only from 0 to l-d in the definition; so, the result of computation is *empty* if d is greater than l. Your example with d=4 and l=3 is not a valid input for this computation. In the actual algorithm in the paper, the degree of g is less than the length of the sequence.

Although g(z^(-1)) is not a polynomial (it has negative powers of z), it is closely related to the [reciprocal polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial), which is what Ben Voigt mentioned in a comment. Precisely, g(z^(-1)) = z^(-d)h(z) where h is the polynomial with coefficients given by `g(end:-1:1)`.

After computing `conv(h,s)`, there are two more things to do. The factor of z^(-d) reduces the exponents by d, and then we are to keep only the exponents from 0 to l-d. Combine both things into one by throwing out the first d and the last d elements of the result of `conv`.

```
g = [1 2 0 0 2];
s = [3 1 4 1 5 9 2 6 5];
d = length(g)-1;
c = conv(g(end:-1:1),s);
result = c(d+1:end-d);
```

result: `[15  27  10  23  33]`. Notice it has the length `length(s)-d`, as expected.

Comment: Thank @Behaviour, great explanation. Do you see the algorithm 2 in the paper (above paper). In the step 7, the author mentioned a multiplication of two polynominal (g_(k+1)=g_k*f_(k+1)). Do you think that it isalso convolution between two coefficient  of polynomial, Right?

Comment: Yes, step 7 is multiplication of polynomials, which means you can find the coefficients of the product with `conv`.

Comment: Yes, sir. However, I am confusing the step 6 to step 7. In step 6, the author said that f_(k+1) to be the minimal polynomial of the sequence in produced in step 5( look like your "result" variance). And step 7 he performed the multiplication between two polynomial( by conv as we said). Hence, we can understand that firstly, we have sequence in step 5-(your result variance) and then we using Berlekamp-Massey to find the minimal polynomial f of result variance. Finally, we take convolution between f and g in step 7. Is it right? I read it many time for this part, but it is so complication

Comment: Yes, this is how I understand the algorithm too.

Comment: In the final step, result is exponents from 0 to l-d. Why you use result = c(d+1:end-d); instead of result = c(1:leng(s)-d); , in which l=length(s). Thank you

Comment: There is a shift by d due to the factor of z to power -d, as said in the answer.

Comment: But as definition, d is degree of g(z) (is not g(power -z))and l is degree of s(z). Please explain help me

Comment: I found one document about that problem. Let see my update question. It looks like the your understand